# Blurry envmap in MeshStandardMateiral in editor

Tags: three.js, textures

I have a problem with a blurry envmap on a `MeshStandardMaterial` in the editor.

This is the result in the current version of the editor (r125) on a `MeshStandardMaterial` with 0 roughness and 1.00 metalness

[image: Current editor - MeshStandardMaterial](https://imgur.com/a/jogKpBW)]
This is the result when I use a `MeshBasicMaterial` with the same editor:

[image]

Help will be much appreciated, Thanks

EDIT:

This is the texture: [image]

Comment: Do you mind sharing the texture in this thread?

Comment: @Mugen87 I added the texture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't compare the environment map implementation between `MeshBasicMaterial` and `MeshStandardMaterial` (which is a PBR material). As mentioned by the documentation, a texture applied to [MeshStandardMaterial.envMap](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/materials/MeshStandardMaterial.envMap) should be pre-processed by `PMREMGenerator`. The editor does not do this for the `envMap` property right now.

Comment: What would it take to for me to add support for this in the editor? I've taken the `PMREMGenerator` created in Viewport.js, and called its `fromEquirectangular` method on the envmap texture. I got a sharper image, but yet still blurry.